# How to Count Line Items in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I modify the syntax below so it only counts and totals line items that have an ItemPrice value that’s greater than 400.

```
USE Shop;


SELECT
    c.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderCount,
    SUM((i.DiscountAmount-i.ItemPrice) * i.Quantity) AS TotalOrderAmount
FROM Customers AS c 
JOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
JOIN OrderItems AS i ON o.OrderID = i.OrderID
GROUP BY c.EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT(c.EmailAddress) > 1
ORDER BY TotalOrderAmount DESC;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` clause to filter out rows:

```
SELECT
    c.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(o.OrderID) AS OrderCount,
    SUM((i.DiscountAmount-i.ItemPrice) * i.Quantity) AS TotalOrderAmount
  FROM Customers AS c 
  JOIN Orders AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
  JOIN OrderItems AS i ON o.OrderID = i.OrderID
  WHERE i.ItemPrice > 400 -- Added a filtering condition here
  GROUP BY c.EmailAddress
  HAVING COUNT(c.EmailAddress) > 1
  ORDER BY TotalOrderAmount DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

- The WHERE clause is used to filter records.
- The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a
  specified condition

So you need a where clause for filtering, just use where clause after join

```
Where ItemPrice > 400
```